# What is the "flow area" for a screen/mesh?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I'm trying to find out, for a given duct area, how large an area of woven mesh (like bug screen) do I need for minimal pressure drop?

Is there a rule of thumb or approximation for "effective flow area" for mesh size "M" and wire diameter "d"?

Thanks
Doug

Comment: This is more of an engineering question rather than a physics question, so I've voted it be closed. You might consider resubmitting it on [Engineering Stack Exchange](//engineering.stackexchange.com).